# Title not showing up on Form

Tags: forms

I have the following code and for some reason my title is not showing up on the form display. I've tried flushing the caches a million times, clearing my cookie cache, and refreshing the browser and even changing the code to read

```
'#title' = t('Module tool'),
```

It doesn't work. The title never shows up although all the rest of my form displays and works fine. Any idea what might be going on here?

Current code:

```
function modulename_menu() {
  $items['modulename'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'title' => 'Module Tool', // doesn't display
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('modulename_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['modulename/secondLevel'] = array
  (
    'title' => 'Other Title', // page redirect; displays fine
    'page callback' => 'pathfindertool_recommendations_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

So this was FIXED by removing this line:

```
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
```

Comment: Try removing 'type'. That should do it.

Comment: What title do you see, instead of the one you are expecting?

Comment: So weird. You were right @Kartagis although I don't know why. I removed the 'type' and flushed caches...sure enough the title appeared again. I had the 'type' in there the whole time and it worked before, it's not a new addition. The other thing that started working after 'fixing' it was the breadcrumb navigation on the page redirect modulename/secondlevel started appearing again also. I couldn't explain this if I tried. There was no title appearing before I fixed this.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That was an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I know this is fixed but title technically should've shown with the 'type' set, it is set default to 'MENU_NORMAL_ITEM' without setting. However, in the docs it shows 'type' lower in the array, could have had something to do with this issue. I've never started with 'type' to test but I've seen other places where order does matter in the render arrays. Just a note for others in the future. Doc page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Comment: That makes sense to me; thanks for adding it @burnsjeremy.